# get NullPointerException when converting JAVA String to JSON object

Tags: java, json

I'm writing a java web application to retrieve tweets by using Twitter API. I got a Search method and trying to call the method at jsp page.

```
public class SearchTwitter {

private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "*************";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "****************";
private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN = "*********************";
private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "*****************";

public String Search(String query) throws Exception {
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
            CONSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    query = query.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    String twitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=" + query + "&src=typd";
    URL url = new URL(twitterURL);
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request.setDoOutput(true);
    request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setRequestMethod("GET");
    consumer.sign(request);
    request.connect();
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent());
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
    System.out.println("Getting data ...");
    String line;
    do {
        line = buff.readLine();
        text.append(line);
    } while (line != null);
    String strResponse = text.toString();
    return strResponse;
}
```

}

The Search method returns a string

```
            <%
            SearchTwitter stw = new SearchTwitter();
            String tweet = request.getParameter("query");

            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(stw.Search(tweet));
            JSONArray statuses = result.getJSONArray("statuses");
            for (int i = 0; i < statuses.length(); i++) {
                String time = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getString("created_at");
                String user = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name");
                String text = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getString("text");
                System.out.println(time.toString());
                System.out.println(user.toString());
                System.out.println(text.toString());
            }
        %>
```

And i'm trying to convert the String to JSON object, but it shows HTTP 500 NullPointerException error
I don't know where i'm getting wrong because i'm new to JAVA.
Could anybody help? Really appreciate!

Comment: Put up a stacktrace and show which line of code it points to

Comment: Just wondering: what makes you think that writing a java web application is a good starting point for a Java newbie? I mean: if you want to learn the language; why don't you start with tutorials/books that especially target newbies? If you are not doing this to learn java - why are you using java then (instead of a language in which you are more skilled?)

Comment: query = query.replaceAll(" ", "%20");                   It points to this line

Comment: I know it is not a good starting point for Java... but this is one of my uni class i'm taking. Seems it is little bit hard for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error most likely happens because

```
String tweet = request.getParameter("query");
```

returns `null`, that is, it cannot find the parameter and returns `null`.

After that you attempt to perform actions on null at:

```
query = query.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

but since `null` cannot perform `.replaceAll` it throws a `NullPointerException`

There are different ways to deal with this:

For example, you could check for `null` right after retrieving the tweet variable like so:

```
    <%
        SearchTwitter stw = new SearchTwitter();
        String tweet = request.getParameter("query");

        if(tweet!=null){
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(stw.Search(tweet));
            JSONArray statuses = result.getJSONArray("statuses");
            for (int i = 0; i < statuses.length(); i++) {
                String time = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getString("created_at");
                String user = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name");
                String text = statuses.getJSONObject(i).getString("text");
                System.out.println(time.toString());
                System.out.println(user.toString());
                System.out.println(text.toString());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to retrieve query!");
        }
    %>
```

So if the tweet variable comes up `null` then instead of time user and text you'll print "Unable to retrieve query!" etc.

Comment: Yes but i got an input text form in jsp page, and `query` is the name. `<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Enter your keyword">` why would this error happened since i have no chance to give input. It throws `NullPointerException` directly.

Comment: I got those tweets!! Thank you so much. But i am still wondering why the results are retrieved after an `if` check. Why it returns `null` without check

Comment: That **is** strange... But glad you got it working in the end.